# error when installing windows-build-tools and nodejsv 18.0.0

Tags: javascript, windows-build-tools

With python2.7 and buildtools installed manually. Python is in the path

```
npm ERR! gyp verb clean removing "build" directory
npm ERR! gyp verb command configure []
npm ERR! gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python2.7" in the PATH
```

https://pastebin.com/YseQXVE4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't recommended to install `windows-build-tools`, as it is deprecated, and there are build tools from the Node.js installer.

---

To install it, follow the steps below.

1. Head to [nodejs.org](https://nodejs.org/), and download and run the LTS installer.
2. On the page where it asks you about installing the build tools, check the box.
3. When the installation has concluded, a PowerShell window will open and run the commands to install the tools.

---

**EDIT:** According to *LeMIT*'s comment,

> A complete uninstallation of Node.js, Python, and Visual Studio (including a registry cleanup) helped me.

---

This should install the build tools.

- Python 2.7
- Visual Studio 20--

Comment: A complete uninstallation of nodejs, python, and visual studio (including a registry cleanup) helped me

Comment: Thanks! Glad it helped! I've added that in the answer.